# Intersystems Caché SQL. Different behaviour trailing withespaces vs leading withespaces

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache, trailing, intersystems, objectscript

**Given:**

- A table tA with an "ID" and a "Description" columns
- "Description" is a string column.
- The contents of the table are:

  **ID    ||  Description**
  1     ||    "String1"
  2     ||    "String2"
  3     ||    "String3"

If I execute the following SQL query:
*"SELECT ID FROM tA WHERE Description = 'String2'"* it returns 2 (as expected)

**But:**

If I execute the following SQL query:
*"SELECT ID FROM tA WHERE Description = 'String2              '"* (trailing withespaces) it also returns 2! (as it is an exact comparison, it should return NONE)

If I execute the following SQL query:
*"SELECT ID FROM tA WHERE Description = '           String2'"* (leading withespaces) it returns NONE (as expected)

Do you know what is the reason of this difference in behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant speak for Cache but this is a common behaviour in databases mandated in the SQL92 standard: *pad strings before comparing so they have the same length* - in general this means trailing white space is ignored, where as leading white space is not. (presumably this was done to ease working with fixed width char types)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "%EXACT" around your column name. This should return no records:  "SELECT ID FROM tA WHERE %EXACT(Description) = 'String2 '"